# filter rows with only one condition on multiple columns

Tags: google-apps-script

`Hello, I'm a very beginner at Googlesheet script. I've got a table with 8 columns and 300 rows. I would like to filter rows and keep only rows when a condition`your text is met for one of the column`

```
function filterRows() {   
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();   
const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");   
const v = sh.getRange("G3").getValue();
console.log(v)
```

`it's working, I've got the correct value`

`I would like to filter (not hide) rows where its value in column B OR column D OR column F equals to v. it's not working at all, I'm only hidding Row4 so no filtering and no be able to test a condition for one of the column vs.forEach((r,i) => {     if(r[0] == v) {       sh.hideRows(4)     } else {       sh.hideRows(4);     }   }) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function filterRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const v = vsh.getRange("A1").getValue();
  const frs = vs.filter(r => r[1] == v || r[3] == v || r[5] == v);
  Logger.log('v:%s\nUnfilteredRows:\n%s\nFilteredRows:\n%s',v,JSON.stringify(vs).replace(/],/g,'],\n'),JSON.stringify(frs).replace(/],/g,'},\n'))
}
```

Logger.logs

```
v:11.0
UnfilteredRows:
[[3,23,20,30,17,34,20,10,23,31],
[13,0,8,11,24,23,13,15,24,9],
[14,16,21,30,32,18,33,25,32,1],
[23,17,9,19,0,28,18,21,19,3],
[28,29,26,26,6,9,13,1,5,34],
[13,1,26,13,17,20,9,30,5,2],
[5,19,21,34,1,28,17,24,17,1],
[28,32,9,7,7,11,1,23,28,3],
[32,25,22,9,7,5,8,26,4,29],
[6,27,34,33,34,20,34,32,33,10],
[32,13,18,23,2,27,34,6,23,22],
[9,4,22,14,13,3,20,18,18,8],
[28,18,3,2,13,12,2,9,5,9],
[26,13,19,23,14,28,28,24,19,15],
[16,18,12,11,28,13,22,9,16,22],
[9,19,31,16,1,28,2,34,28,33],
[9,9,5,19,1,4,10,18,12,25],
[1,28,24,5,26,8,26,18,28,23],
[26,26,31,15,17,11,10,6,18,17],
[31,4,24,28,23,29,30,10,4,27],
[28,27,8,8,3,8,23,32,29,29],
[0,4,10,2,6,26,18,21,22,22],
[7,21,18,27,5,16,0,6,30,3],
[14,25,20,9,32,15,31,1,18,14],
[25,18,18,34,17,17,12,32,6,6],
[19,19,22,1,5,31,3,33,12,34],
[0,18,19,9,32,8,6,28,1,16],
[3,31,27,13,11,7,6,22,33,26],
[13,28,2,17,30,4,11,14,29,28],
[19,6,29,32,13,23,24,19,26,5],
[26,19,9,31,16,33,33,4,22,20],
[13,16,7,22,22,8,34,1,13,13],
[5,3,12,27,9,32,13,26,3,19],
[34,27,20,29,2,3,18,25,5,5],
[21,8,5,14,13,24,15,8,30,13]]
FilteredRows:
[[13,0,8,11,24,23,13,15,24,9},
[28,32,9,7,7,11,1,23,28,3},
[16,18,12,11,28,13,22,9,16,22},
[26,26,31,15,17,11,10,6,18,17]]
```

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Posting result to another sheet:

```
function filterRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const v = vsh.getRange("A1").getValue();
  const frs = vs.filter(r => r[1] == v || r[3] == v || r[5] == v);
  Logger.log('v:%s\nUnfilteredRows:\n%s\nFilteredRows:\n%s',v,JSON.stringify(vs).replace(/],/g,'],\n'),JSON.stringify(frs).replace(/],/g,'},\n'))
  vsh.clearContents();
  vsh.getRange(1,1,frs.length,frs[0].length).setValues(frs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

The result you show is the one that I hope to get. But for some reason, it didn't work on my side. Here is the result that I get

v:Sébastien
UnfilteredRows:
[["nom","prenom","adresse","prenom1","nom1","ecole1","ecole2"],
["Dupond","Sébastien","31 rue du docteur","Maxime","Dupond","George","Jean"],
["Durand","Sébastien","19 rue du paradis","Baptiste","Durand","Eric","Jean"],
["Dumichel","Pierre","17 av dutilleul","Maxime","Dumichel","George","Jean"],
["Dupond","Sébastien","31 rue du docteur","Maxime","Dupond","Paul","Eric"]]
FilteredRows:
[]

Comment: On FilteredRows, I was expecting to get row 2,3,5 (first row is for headers). The variable v gets the correct value which is 'Sebastien'

Comment: Also, I would like to display the result in the Sheet where are the initial data to allow all users to see the result

Comment: I need more details to display them

Comment: Now, I've got the desired filtered results.

But, I'm unable to show the filtered results in the original sheet. How could I manage it please?

Comment: Which details do you need to set the filter in the GoogleSheet? please tell me

Comment: I  added to my answer